# Exclude class from debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I remember that there was some type of decorator to exclude certain classes from being show while debugging.

Reason:

Have multiple classes. If debugger jumps to another class (thread) during debugging, that can be very anoying. Some helper classes should rather be stepepd over.

But I just can't find this decorator anywhere. Does anyone remember how to exclude a file so that debugger does not step into it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are looking for the [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx).

You can apply this attribute to a `class`, a `method`, a `struct` or a `constructor`. Remember that the debugger will *always* step through the code that is flagged with this attribute, even if you put a breakpoint in it.

Answer (score 8):

You're probably looking for [`DebuggerStepThrough`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx) attribute.

Answer (score 2):

There is an attribute called `DebuggerStepThrough`: [DebuggerStepThroughAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerstepthroughattribute.aspx)

> Instructs the debugger to step through the code instead of stepping
>   into the code. This class cannot be inherited.

It can be applied to `class`, `struct`, `constructor` and `method`.